# How to create new table after publish app

Tags: android, sqlite

During an upgrade, I want to add a new table to my database, but I want also not lose the data from the other tables when upgrading the application. Can someone tell me, how can I do ?

It is possible ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_A_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REPORTING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SUCC_SENDING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE); // new table
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,  final int oldVersion,
                      final int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GROUPS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOTIFICATIONS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + A_GROUP);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MESSAGES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + REPORTING);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SUCC_SENDING);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RECEIVES); //new table
    onCreate(db);
}
```

My new table is `RECEIVES`

---

**Updated**

Current version is `1`. I want to change it to `2` .

```
public MainDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_A_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REPORTING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SUCC_SENDING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE);
    //db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE); //new table
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,  final int oldVersion,
                      final int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GROUPS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOTIFICATIONS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + A_GROUP);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MESSAGES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + REPORTING);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SUCC_SENDING);
   // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RECEIVES); // new table
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increment your database version number every time your schema changes.

In the `OnUpgrade` method, check the old and new versions and write the code appropriate to upgrade from one version to the other. You will likely have multiple checks for the version number as each version is published which allows you to incrementally upgrade. It is not good practice to call your `onCreate` from the the `OnUpgrade` method. This should only be used to create the first iteration of your database

e.g
Assuming the current/new version is 3

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,  final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {

    if (oldversion<2) {
        // Code to upgrade from V1 to V2. 
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE);
    }

    if (oldversion<3) {
        // Code to upgrade from V2 to V3 
    }

    // Other version checks added as needed etc. etc

}
```

Anyone with a V1 database will have both code blocks executed. Whilst a V2 database will only have the second one execute. Add a new check with each version increment.  All code within the `OnUpgrade` method runs inside a transaction so if any part of it fails, the whole database is rolled back to the state it was in before the method was called.

Your `OnCreate` method should always contain the code to create the current\latest version of your database.

Currently you are dropping all of your tables and recreating your whole database. This removes all previously created data.

**Update**
The specific code you request for your v2 would be:

```
public MainDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create V2 database. This is only called if the database does not exist

    db.execSQL(CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_A_GROUPS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REPORTING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SUCC_SENDING_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE); 
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,  final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {

    // OnUpgrade is called if your database exists and the version number is less than the version specified in the Constructor

    if (oldversion<2) {
        // Code to upgrade from V1 to V2. 
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE); // Add the new table only
    }

    if (oldversion<3) {
        // When V3 is released, add code here to 
        // upgrade from V2 to V3 
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question. plz give me correct code. thanks so much. `RECEIVES` is new table.

Comment: This  already is correct. It just has extra information for when you want to update to V3

Comment: ok, but when I change version code to 2, all data of other tables will remove. I don't want to lose my data.

Comment: No the data remains intact because your onupgrade code does not contain anything that would cause it to be deleted. Your data only gets removed if you remove it by for example, dropping and recreating tables. My code ONLY adds a table. It does not do anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all of the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS commands and place

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE);
```

in the onUpgrade method. Making it like so;

```
    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,  final int oldVersion,
                      final int newVersion) {

     db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: This would likely throw an error when the `OnUpgrade` method calls the `OnCreate` method because it would attempt to create tables that already exist.

Comment: It woulnd't because onCreate isn't called if it is an upgrade. onUpgrade is.. and if onUpgrade is being called then db.execSQL(CREATE_RECEIVES_TABLE); has not been called (assuming that wasn't in you're previous version. onUpgrade will only be called instead of onCreate if the database version number is incremented and people have an old database version. You still need the create receives table in onCreate for people which are not upgrading and are downloading version 2 of your app straight away.

Comment: You are specifically calling oncreate in your onupgrade method so it WILL be called